# model.layers in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, theano, keras

In Keras, `model.layers` is a flattened list of the layers comprising the model graph. I saw some example that defines `first_layer = model.layers[-1]`. Why we use -1 here to represent the first layer, should that be zero.

Are there functions that can output the object type of `model.layers`. Is `print(model.players)` the only way to see the content of `model.layers`?

Comment: According to https://keras.io/models/sequential/#useful-attributes-of-model, it looks like `model.layers` is just a list. `model.layers[-1]` would give you the last element of the list, which we can't explain further without seeing the actual example.

Comment: Yes, its the last layer, not the first one.

Comment: Is `model.layers[0]` the first one then?
I was about to ask the question.